# What is the correct name for this data format?

Tags: naming-conventions, data-formats

I am a perfectionist and need a good name for a function that parses data that has this type of format:

```
userID:12,year:2010,active:1
```

Maybe perhaps

```
parse_meta_data()
```

I'm not sure what the correct name for this type of data format is.  Please advise!  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know a name of this type of data format.  You'll need to be more specific about the details of the format.  Are the delimiters configurable?  Can delimiters occur in attribute names or values, and if so, how?

Comment: "metadata" is data about your data.

Comment: Nope, delimiters cannot occur in attribute names or values and this data will be inserted into a database and I'm not sure what you mean by if they are configurable.  Basically, in the database the data will look like that, but when retrieved from the database, it will be converted to an array.  Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse_dict or parse_map

Comment: I went with the naming convention dict or dictionary, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Except for the lack of braces and the quotes around the keys, it looks like either JSON or a Python dict.

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_tagged_csv()

parse_csv()

parse_structured_csv()

parse_csv_with_attributes()

parse csvattr()
```

Comment: parse_csv_with_colon_separated_keys_and_values() ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a proprietary data format, you can name it whatever you want. But it would be good to use a common term like *serialized data* or *mapping list*.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a list of simple items, each of which has a name and a value, then "key-value pairs" is probably the right term.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
parse_named_records()
```

Answer (score 0):

ParseCommaSeparatedNameValuePairs()

ParseDelimitedNameValuePairs()

ParseCommaSeparatedKeyValuePairs()

ParseDelimitedKeyValuePairs()

Comment: Its funny that everyone has their own ideal structues in their brain.

Answer (score 0):

From the one line you gave, `ParseJson()` seems appropriate